# Strapi server now starting on cloud9

Tags: strapi, cloud9

I try to install strapi on cloud9
I entered the following command

```
strapi new strapi
cd strapi
strapi start
```

The following server has started, but I can't access http://localhost:8080/admin

I know 8080 port isinaccessible.

so how do I access localhost and setup first step of strapi?

plz

Comment: `http://YOURSERVERUP:1337/admin`

Comment: cloud9 only accepts 8080, 8081 or 8082 ports.

This time I will give up and use contentful.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.env` file to choose a port while starting Strapi.

```
HOST=YOURSERVERIP
PORT=8080
DATABASE_CLIENT=sqlite
```

---

Or you can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to get Public URLs for your Strapi project

```
ngrok http  YOURSERVERIP:8080
```